# How can i access std::ostream file?

Tags: c++, ostream

I have an output file as .gcode format which is being written by std::ostream* object. I want to edit in the output file and again have to write into the std::ostream* object.
Is there any steps to be proceed further?

Comment: By now you should [know how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The class std::ostream doesn't handle buffering or hardware I/O. It only handles formatting and conversions. it needs to be associated with a class derived from std::streambuf in order for that output to go anywhere.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
int main()
{std::ostream stream(nullptr); // useless ostream (badbit set)
stream << "Hello World"; // nothing happens (well, failbit is also set)

stream.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf()); // uses cout's buffer
stream << "Hello World\n"; // prints to cout

std::stringbuf str;
stream.rdbuf(&str); // uses str
stream << "Hello World"; // writes to str
std::cout << "str = '" << str.str() << "'\n";}
```